# Problem while adding new font in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am trying to use Kalpurush font for Bengali text in my article. For this, I have already downloaded the kalpurush.ttf file from [here](https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html) and have uploaded it in the project directory in Overleaf. I have added the following commands before the `\begin{document}` command:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\newfontfamily\ben{kalpurush}[kalpurush.ttf]
```

And then I write Bengali text anywhere like this:

```
{\ben কম্পিউটার বিজ্ঞান}
```

But when I compile using XeLaTex, the compilation gets timed out every time. Is there any error in my approach? I can't set Kalpurush font as my main font as I need to write some Bengali text along with mostly English text.

Comment: Try `\newfontfamily\ben{kalpurush.ttf}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
\newfontfamily\ben{kalpurush.ttf}
```